# Inserting dateTime into mysql won't work

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo, insert

I am trying to insert a date (joinedate of user) i use this code:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = $this->_pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO web_users VALUES(:joinedate)'); 
$query->bindParam(':joinedate', $date);
$query->execute();
```

This is in pdo and when i execute this it will just set null in the database. The database column is a datetime so it should work.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Not sure if this will help but can you try placing the bindParam statement before the actual query..

Comment: you haven't specified any fields, so unless you only have a date/time field in your web_users table, the query is NOT going to work. and if you're just inserting the current date/time, why bother with the php-side date fiddling? `insert ... values (now())` would work just as well.

Comment: If joinedate is my only field that will not matter. Seconde, this is not the only thing in need to insert with dates.. And it is not always the now() date.

Comment: Binding before the query will absolutly not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Marc B stated, you need to specify the column unless you have only one column. And you are stating

```
$query->executy();
```

which should be

$query->execute();

And you have a typo here:

```
:joinedate is not like in bind_param :joindedate
```

**Code:**

```
$query = $this->_pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO web_users (column) VALUES(:joinedate)'); 
              //^are you sure this is right? 
$query->bindParam(':joinedate', $date);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: This did not help, still having the same problem.

Comment: If this didn't help you need to show how you are connecting to your DB

Comment: That is not needed, because everything else i do works. Everything else i put it shows, only datetime things not.

Comment: well, if you've checked everything in my answer (keep in mind I updated it because I found some other issues) the error is somewhere else... Everything else in your question's code is ok. also make sure which is the default for your datetime column and if it is one

Comment: I made some weird typo too over different classes, Thanks for you help! Appreciate it very much.